# Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported - GRUB error - Ubuntu 16.04, luksPartition, boot-repair does not work

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, uefi, luks

Just after starting my laptop I am seeing black screen with the message in the title. This has happened when I've had 2nd drive connected to my laptop and I've installed fresh Ubuntu 16.04 on it. Apparently this action broke boot on my main drive Ubuntu 16.04.

I was trying to follow this guide:
https://itsfoss.com/fix-minimal-bash-line-editing-supported-grub-error-linux/

Unfortunately this does not work to me.

This is what I've from boot-repair: http://paste2.org/8sPXwAjj

EDIT: My problem was that I didn't boot pendrive in UEFI mode, even though it still does not work, although the output looks cleaner: http://paste2.org/7PWwdh03

Any ideas how can I fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to boot from the EFI-bootable USB pendrive.
Then decrypt the luks with cryptsetup.
Then run the `boot-repair`. 
Got my OS back :)